# Should my web server be accessible directly by its IP address, and how would I go setting that up?

Tags: nginx, security, ip, configuration, django

Currently I have a Django server, which works normally if you go to [www.notmyactualwebsite.com](http://www.notmyactualwebsite.com). However, I get a bunch of bot accessing the IP address directly, i.e. 12.34.56.78:443 to which Django will throw an exception and alert me that I might need to add 12.34.56.78:443 to the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting.

This makes me wonder: Should I indeed be allowing access to my site by direct IP? I can't imagine many humans would actually do that, so it is okay to just leave it?

Comment: Did you not put a web server in front of Django?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have a nginx server sitting in front of Django, but it pretty much forwards all traffic over. Have I screwed that up?

Comment: You probably edited the default `server` block that it shipped with, to serve your domain name, instead of creating your own separate one. It's a common mistake.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Do you mean the `server_name` line should include the IP address as well?

Comment: **Should I indeed be allowing access to my site by direct IP?** - Why? For what purpose? Users aren't going to connect to it directly by it's ip address.

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes, that's exactly what I'm thinking. Yet my understanding is most sites *are* accessible directly by IP?

Comment: Most sites are not accessed directly by users typing the ip address in the address bar of their web browser. By design the FQDN of the website is resolved to the ip address and that's what the browser ultimately connects to... BUT... users don't usually type the ip address in the address bar... because they don't know the ip address. So should you configure your server to accommodate users typing the ip address in the address bar? My opinion is no.

Comment: The opposite: You should leave sites-available/default as it was shipped by Debian, and make a copy of it to customize for your own web site. Your IP addresses should not appear anywhere in the configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm actually using DigitalOcean's pre-shipped nginx+django image, so it's already a separate, non-default config. I think I've got it now though! Please let me know if my answer looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the the comments to my question and the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846521/i-continuously-receive-invalid-http-host-header-error-email-after-i-upgrade-my I've learned that:

1. Apparently most sites do not permit direct IP connection so you too do not need to accommodate such cases.
2. My nginx setup should be the layer that prevents such access, and it can do so with these default blocks catching all non-accepted server names:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

Now, this actually doesn't work. I don't understand SSL certificates fully, so I'd love for someone to comment why this is, but even when accessing the site normally i.e. NOT using IP address correctly, this server config would cause ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED or ERR_CONNECTION_RESET errors. I found the answer, which is that you need to add the SSL certificates because this is a HTTPS endpoint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677044/nginx-ssl-certificate-directive-doesnt-work-within-server-block-browser-shows

So I copied the SSL certificates from my regular django server block, and now the SSL block looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/notmyactualwebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/notmyactualwebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Except, apparently it's better not to serve your domain-based SSL certificate for the IP. So you can generate your own according to the answer here [Block direct access to webserver IP via HTTPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/794953/block-direct-access-to-webserver-ip-via-https) :

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt -subj '/CN=<SERVER-IP>'`

And then your final result looks like:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;

    # This will actually trigger a browser SSL error because they won't trust
    # your self-signed certificate but it's probably to a bot anyway
    ssl_certificate         /path/to/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /path/to/privateKey.key;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

Comment: You need just *any* certificate/key pair for web server to start listening in SSL mode. You don't need that certificate to be globally valid and so on, it's just for web server (actually, ssl library) to be happy. If other (non-default) virtual hosts are configured with concrete server names, this `default_server` one will not catch any valid user, it'll serve only those who don't use any of your configured (in other `server` blocks) host names, but you are going to reject them with 444 anyway, so there is nothing bad in presenting them with a invalid certificate.